# QZ TRAY PRINITING ORDER NOT IN SEQ

Tags: qz-tray

I'm trying to print qz tray from javascript. 
I have barcode with number in ascending order 1,2,3,4, 5 and so on.
I looping the seq correctly . but when printed out, it was not in order.

```
    setTimeout("directPrint2()",1000);

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function directPrint2(){
  var data;
  var xhttp;
  var v_carton = "' || x_str_carton ||'";       
  var carton_arr = v_carton.split('','');                                                                                                        
  var v1 =  "' ||
replace(x_zebra_printer_id, '\', '|') ||
'".replace(/\|/g,"\\");
  if(v1 == ""){
      alert("Please setup ZPL Printer");
  }
  else{                                                   
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              data = [ toNative(this.responseText) ];
              printZPL(data, v1);
          }
      };

     for (var j = 0; j < carton_arr.length; j++){                                                         

      var url = "' || x_wms_url ||
'WWW_URL.direct_print_label?in_carton_no="+toValidStr(carton_arr[j]);

      xhttp.open("GET", url, false);                                                                                                       
      xhttp.send();   
      sleep(5000);                                                                                                             
    }  
  }               
};

',
'javascript'
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from your example:

- I do not see any looping logic in the example calling the `printZPL` function,
- `printZPL` isn't a QZ Tray function and you're missing the code snippet which it calls.  Usually this would be `qz.print(config, data);`.

Regardless of the missing information, the `qz.print(...)` API is ES6/Promise/A+ based meaning **if you want to call `qz.print` multiple times in a row you need to use a Promise-compatible technique. (e.g. `.then(...)` syntax)** between your print calls as explained in the [Chaining Requests](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-Raw-Printing#chaining-requests) guide.

To avoid this, you can concatenate all ZPL data into one large `data` array.  Be careful not to [spool too much data at once](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-Raw-Printing#advanced-print-spooling).

If you know exactly how many jobs you'll be appending, you can hard-code the promise chain:

```
qz.websocket.connect()
.then(function() { 
   return qz.printers.find("zebra");              // Pass the printer name into the next Promise
})
.then(function(printer) {
   var config = qz.configs.create(printer);       // Create a default config for the found printer
   var data = ['^XA^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDRAW ZPL EXAMPLE^FS^XZ'];   // Raw ZPL
   return qz.print(config, data);
})
.catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
```

Finally, if you do NOT know in advanced how many calls to `qz.print(...)` you can use a Promise loop as explained in the [Promise Loop](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-Raw-Printing#promise-loop) guide.

```
function promiseLoop() {
    var data = [
        "^XA\n^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDPRINT 1 ^FS\n^XZ\n",
        "^XA\n^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDPRINT 2 ^FS\n^XZ\n",
        "^XA\n^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDPRINT 3 ^FS\n^XZ\n",
        "^XA\n^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDPRINT 4 ^FS\n^XZ\n"
    ];
    var configs = [
        { "printer": "ZDesigner LP2844-Z" },
        { "printer": "ZDesigner LP2844-Z" },
        { "printer": "ZDesigner LP2844-Z" },
        { "printer": "ZDesigner LP2844-Z" }
    ];
    var chain = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        (function(i_) {
            //setup this chain link
            var link = function() {
                return qz.printers.find(configs[i_].printer).then(function(found) {
                    return qz.print(qz.configs.create(found), [data[i_]]);
                });
            };

            chain.push(link);
        })(i);
        //closure ensures this promise's concept of `i` doesn't change
    }

    //can be .connect or `Promise.resolve()`, etc
    var firstLink = new RSVP.Promise(function(r, e) { r(); });

    var lastLink = null;
    chain.reduce(function(sequence, link) {
        lastLink = sequence.then(link);
        return lastLink;
    }, firstLink);

    //this will be the very last link in the chain
    lastLink.catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

**Note:** The Promise Loop is no longer needed in QZ Tray 2.1.  Instead, since 2.1, an [array of `config` objects and `data` arrays can be provided instead](https://github.com/qzind/tray/issues/161).